# Autoload Python Script at Cinnamon Login

Tags: python, linux, gnome, cinnamon

I am using Cinnamon desktop on the top of arch linux. I wanted to load a python script at desktop login which informs me about battery stats, so I created a batterymonitor.desktop entry under ~/.config/autostart. The contents of batterymonitor.desktop are:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=python /home/<myusername>/scripts/battery_monitor.py
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=BatteryMonitor
Name=BatteryMonitor
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

But the problem is that the script is not loading at cinnamon login. I have also confirmed that the script is executable.
Can you help to load this script at cinnamon login?
Ps. The script is working fine when launched from terminal.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use `cinnamon-settings`'s "startup applications" section, since this is its purpose ;)

You should also try to use python's full executable path (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`) instead of only `python`.

Comment: Already tried both of your suggestions but in vain, thanks though :)